# .sh file unable echo out variable that defined in bash

Tags: bash, shell, variables, scripting

I am trying to generate an HTML file with .sh and variable that defined in the shell

```
     [root@ip-xxx-xx-x-xxx Reporting]: IMAGE_TAG=xyzabc
```

.sh file code

```
      #!/bin/bash
      echo "<!DOCTYPE html>" > fargateproductiondeploy.html
      echo "<html> <body>" >> fargateproductiondeploy.html
     echo "<h2>Following Docker container 
     will be deployed  will be Deployed in production up on Approval </h2> 
     <ol>" >> fargateproductiondeploy.html
     echo "<li>$IMAGE_TAG </li>" >> fargateproductiondeploy.html
```

After running the ./generatehtml.sh  out from HTML file was

```
            Following Docker container will be deployed will be Deployed in 
            production upon Approval 
            1.
```

Comment: Does it work if you first do `export IMAGE_TAG=xyzabc` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to export the variable first

```
$ export IMAGE_TAG=xyzabc
$ ./generatehtml.sh
```

or source the file

```
$ IMAGE_TAG=xyzabc
$ . ./generatehtml.sh
```

Preferable to either would be to pass the value as an argument instead.

```
#!/bin/bash
image_tag=$1

echo "<!DOCTYPE html>" > fargateproductiondeploy.html
echo "<html> <body>" >> fargateproductiondeploy.html
echo "<h2>Following Docker container will be deployed  will be Deployed in production up on Approval </h2> <ol>" >> fargateproductiondeploy.html
echo "<li>$image_tag </li>" >> fargateproductiondeploy.html
```

followed by

```
$ ./generatehtml.sh xyzabc
```